# Synaptic on a VPS unser Debian

Tags: linux, debian, vps, synaptic

I am running Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch) on a VPS.
I have installed Xfce 4.12 and accessing my desktop with VNC.
Synaptic was also installed but when I click on it through the menu nothing happens.

I tried on terminal `sudo synaptic` but I have a error message :

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connexion refusée
(synaptic:14180): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :1.0
```

Same error after trying 'sudo gksu saynaptic'

Answer (score 0):

Strange that it doesn't ask for root password.
Try from console

```
$ gksu synaptic
```

Of course You need this gsku to be installed.